# Business Objects : planification with empty request

Tags: business-objects

I'm a beginner in Business Objects version 4.2 and I have planifications every day to send data to my collaborators.

The problem is sometimes my data are empty and I don't want to send an empty email. I saw people saying that I can use publication to do that but I really don't know how that work. In planification I saw that we can planify with "Event" and maybe I can use it for my problem ?

Comment: What Support Pack and Patch are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Support Pack 4 and the exact version is 14.2.4.2410. Sadly, I havn't the "Delivery Rules" tab in my Business Object because of the version as you said. I'll try to use the publications despite the difficulties or I'll check your link. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BusinessObjects 4.2 there are some new options which you can use to only send the report if it has data.

Here is what it looks like when using a publication...

[image]

And here is what it looks like when scheduling without using a publication...

[image]

I am not sure at with which Support Pack this was added. We are on 4.2 SP07 Patch 400.

Alternatively, you can force the report to fail if there is no data using [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/08/avoid-scheduling-when-no-data-in-report/) method.